# How to enter MFA code in each of the multiprocessing Pool threads?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, boto3, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that uploads files to s3 but it asks for MFA code before uploading starts. I am passing the function to the multiprocessing pool which creates two processes and runs the function two times concurrently.

When I run my script, It asks for MFA code twice in the terminal but the script crashes.

How do I enter MFA code in both processes concurrently and authenticate both processes?

**Here is my Python code**:

```
import multiprocessing
import boto3

session = boto3.Session()
s3_client = session.client('s3')

def load_to_s3(file_path):
  response = s3_client.upload_file(file_path, bucket, target_path) # This line asks for MFA
  return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 2)
  response_list = pool.map(load_to_s3, file_path_chunks)
```

Error Messages -
[image]

Comment: Are you going to tell us what an *"MFA"* is? Or what the error message is? Or show us which line caused it?

Comment: @Mark, MFA - Multi-factor authentication. The response line which prompts for MFA code in the terminal pops up two times together due to multithreading and that causes the code to crash.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [multiprocessing.Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock) to make sure that only one process will be authenticated at a time.

Also you may need to create a new client for each process:

> Resource instances are not thread safe and should not be shared across
> threads or processes. These special classes contain additional meta
> data that cannot be shared. **It's recommended to create a new Resource
> for each thread or process**

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html?highlight=multithreading#multithreading-or-multiprocessing-with-resources

Example:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time
import boto3

lock = multiprocessing.Lock()


def load_to_s3(file_path):
    with lock:
        print(file_path)
        # there will be only one process at a time
        # do your work here
        # session = boto3.Session()
        # s3_client = session.client('s3')
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
    file_path_chunks = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    response_list = pool.map(load_to_s3, file_path_chunks)
```

Comment: Hi @u1234x1234, The code that you sent works fine for printing out the paths. But as soon as I uncomment those lines and try to do s3_client.upload_file(), It throws error messages -

Comment: 1
2
C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\getpass.py:100: GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
  return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\getpass.py:100: GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
  return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Enter MFA code for arn:aws:iam::052374110:mfa/Username: Enter MFA code for arn:aws:iam::052374110:mfa/Username:

Comment: 3
4
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Enter MFA code for arn:aws:iam::052374110:mfa/Username: Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Enter MFA code for arn:aws:iam::052374110:mfa/Username: multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""